# Password Protecting multiple folders

Tags: password-protection, directory

I am trying to password protect multiple folders and have different users access specific folders based on the the password the user provides. For example:

- There are folders A, B, C, D.

  - User 1 is a regular employee and should only have access to folder A.
  - User 2 is a Manager and should have access to folders A, B, and C.
  - User 3 is an Admin and has access to all folders.

Is there a way to password protect these folders with variable degrees of access? Can it be done without a scripting languages such as Ruby?

Best,
Ayaz

Comment: The operating system is mac os

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the best you can do is to [make an encrypted disk image](http://www.wikihow.com/Password-Protect-Files-on-a-Mac), no degrees of access.

But password protecting folders are the wrong way to go. Folder protection on Unix (MacOS is a Unix operating system) is usually done with [user and group permissions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm), not passwords.

You'd create groups for each type of permission, assign users to those groups, and put the right group permission on each folder. Typically groups are not about employee hierarchies like "manager" which is too broad, but about roles like "customer_service" or "accounting".

Each user gets an account, that account has its own groups it belongs to, and a password to protect the account. You can change what groups they belong to (and thus what they have access to), and even delete the whole account. This is more flexible and it means if someone leaves the company you don't have to reset all the passwords.

So in your example, everyone gets their own password protected user account they log into. User 1 (the employee) is in group employee. User 2 is in both groups employee and manager. Folder A is owned by group employee (`chgrp employee folderA`). Folders B and C are owned by group manager (`chgrp manager folderB folderC`). All folders are set so others cannot read, write, nor see their contents (`chmod o-rwx`) and so members of the group can (`chmod g+rwx`). You'd do all this using the [Terminal](http://guides.macrumors.com/Terminal).

User 3 has admin access to the machine. That will let them access any folder.

This is just a basic sketch. I'd suggest you read up some on Unix permissions and how to organize them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will start doing research on it today!